# Javascript in html value

Tags: javascript, html

If I have this code: `<input type="text" value="text"/>`

How to do, alert("test") in "value"?

Comment: What things you have tried?

Comment: what is **alert("test") in "value"** supposed to mean?

Comment: Please explain better what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

You HTML encode it:

```
<input type="text" value="alert(&quot;test&quot;)"/>
```

To be clear; what you have isn't actually JavaScript, as the code won't be executed, you have a text that looks like JavaScript code.

The same way of encoding the value applies if you would put it in an attribute that contains code though, like the `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value='alert("test")'/>
```

just use diferent quotation marks ''

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your problem:

1 way:

```
<input type="text" onchange="alert(this.value)">
```

2 way (using jQuery):

```
<input type="text" id="textInput" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#textInput").on("change", function(){ 
  alert($("#textInput").val());
 });
});
</script>
```

If you need to get the value was only alert("text")

```
<input type="text" value='alert("text")'/>
```